# How do you bring up mobile keyboard if input is already in focus?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input which, when `focus`ed, changes the `type` attribute's value.

```
input.on('focus', () => input.attr('type', newThing))
```

This stops the keyboard on mobile browsers from getting pulled up. You have to touch the input again in order for the keyboard to show up.

I tried to use jQuery's `input.focus()` but it does nothing if the input is already in focus.

Comment: maybe the event is being tampered with? The arrow function should have an event param: `(e) => ...`

Comment: "*I have an input which changes its type when focused*" - uh, don't do that?  What do you need this for?